# Undefined reference to SOIL functions

Tags: c++

I am trying to use SOIL to set a JPEG file as a texture in OpenGL. 
I am using CODE::BLOCKS.
I added the .lib file as a linker and .h file in the include folder and I set the '#include' line in my code but when i use SOIL functions in my Build log I have theese errors :

```
mingw32-g++.exe -Wall -g -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\include" -c D:\Programming\just_a_room\main.cpp -o obj\Debug\main.o
mingw32-g++.exe -L"C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib" -o bin\Debug\just_a_room.exe obj\Debug\main.o   -lglut32 -lopengl32 -lglu32 -lwinmm -lgdi32 "C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\libSOIL.a"
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\libSOIL.a(SOIL.o):SOIL.c:(.text+0x3e): undefined reference to `glGetString@4'
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\libSOIL.a(SOIL.o):SOIL.c:(.text+0x72): undefined reference to `glGetString@4'
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\libSOIL.a(SOIL.o):SOIL.c:(.text+0xbe): undefined reference to `glGetString@4'
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\libSOIL.a(SOIL.o):SOIL.c:(.text+0xf2): undefined reference to `glGetString@4'
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\libSOIL.a(SOIL.o):SOIL.c:(.text+0x115): undefined reference to `glGetString@4'
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\libSOIL.a(SOIL.o):SOIL.c:(.text+0x15e): more undefined references to `glGetString@4' follow
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\libSOIL.a(SOIL.o):SOIL.c:(.text+0x1d1): undefined reference to `wglGetProcAddress@4'
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\libSOIL.a(SOIL.o):SOIL.c:(.text+0x4bd): undefined reference to `glBindTexture@8'
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\libSOIL.a(SOIL.o):SOIL.c:(.text+0x5e2): undefined reference to `glTexImage2D@36'
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\libSOIL.a(SOIL.o):SOIL.c:(.text+0x66a): undefined reference to `glTexImage2D@36'
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\libSOIL.a(SOIL.o):SOIL.c:(.text+0x7a3): undefined reference to `glTexParameteri@12'
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\libSOIL.a(SOIL.o):SOIL.c:(.text+0x7c4): undefined reference to `glTexParameteri@12'
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\libSOIL.a(SOIL.o):SOIL.c:(.text+0x7ef): undefined reference to `glTexParameteri@12'
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\libSOIL.a(SOIL.o):SOIL.c:(.text+0x810): undefined reference to `glTexParameteri@12'
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\libSOIL.a(SOIL.o):SOIL.c:(.text+0x831): undefined reference to `glTexParameteri@12'
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\libSOIL.a(SOIL.o):SOIL.c:(.text+0x84f): undefined reference to `glDeleteTextures@8'
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\libSOIL.a(SOIL.o):SOIL.c:(.text+0x90c): undefined reference to `glGenTextures@8'
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\libSOIL.a(SOIL.o):SOIL.c:(.text+0x932): undefined reference to `glTexParameteri@12'
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\libSOIL.a(SOIL.o):SOIL.c:(.text+0x94d): undefined reference to `glTexParameteri@12'
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\libSOIL.a(SOIL.o):SOIL.c:(.text+0x968): undefined reference to `glTexParameteri@12'
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\libSOIL.a(SOIL.o):SOIL.c:(.text+0x98e): undefined reference to `glTexParameteri@12'
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\libSOIL.a(SOIL.o):SOIL.c:(.text+0x9af): undefined reference to `glTexParameteri@12'
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\libSOIL.a(SOIL.o):SOIL.c:(.text+0xdf8): undefined reference to `glReadPixels@28'
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\libSOIL.a(SOIL.o):SOIL.c:(.text+0x100d): undefined reference to `glGetIntegerv@8'
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\libSOIL.a(SOIL.o):SOIL.c:(.text+0x11b4): undefined reference to `glBindTexture@8'
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\libSOIL.a(SOIL.o):SOIL.c:(.text+0x125b): undefined reference to `glTexParameteri@12'
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\libSOIL.a(SOIL.o):SOIL.c:(.text+0x1279): undefined reference to `glTexParameteri@12'
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\libSOIL.a(SOIL.o):SOIL.c:(.text+0x12a1): undefined reference to `glTexParameteri@12'
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\libSOIL.a(SOIL.o):SOIL.c:(.text+0x12bf): undefined reference to `glTexParameteri@12'
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\libSOIL.a(SOIL.o):SOIL.c:(.text+0x13da): undefined reference to `glBindTexture@8'
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\libSOIL.a(SOIL.o):SOIL.c:(.text+0x1427): undefined reference to `glTexImage2D@36'
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\libSOIL.a(SOIL.o):SOIL.c:(.text+0x15a8): undefined reference to `glTexImage2D@36'
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\libSOIL.a(SOIL.o):SOIL.c:(.text+0x161a): undefined reference to `glTexImage2D@36'
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\libSOIL.a(SOIL.o):SOIL.c:(.text+0x1648): undefined reference to `glTexParameteri@12'
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\libSOIL.a(SOIL.o):SOIL.c:(.text+0x1666): undefined reference to `glTexParameteri@12'
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\libSOIL.a(SOIL.o):SOIL.c:(.text+0x168e): undefined reference to `glTexParameteri@12'
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\libSOIL.a(SOIL.o):SOIL.c:(.text+0x16ac): undefined reference to `glTexParameteri@12'
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\libSOIL.a(SOIL.o):SOIL.c:(.text+0x16d7): undefined reference to `glTexParameteri@12'
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\libSOIL.a(SOIL.o):SOIL.c:(.text+0x16f2): undefined reference to `glGenTextures@8'
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\libSOIL.a(SOIL.o):SOIL.c:(.text+0x1773): undefined reference to `glBindTexture@8'
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\libSOIL.a(SOIL.o):SOIL.c:(.text+0x17d3): undefined reference to `glBindTexture@8'
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\libSOIL.a(SOIL.o):SOIL.c:(.text+0x1827): undefined reference to `glTexParameteri@12'
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\libSOIL.a(SOIL.o):SOIL.c:(.text+0x188c): undefined reference to `glTexImage2D@36'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status'
```

Comment: these are linker errors. It means it didn't find the library (so includes and headers are ok, focus on .lib and linker settings)

Comment: it looks like you are nt the opengl library it is not found

Comment: I downloaded the header and library files from here  (http://www.lonesock.net/soil.html) and linked the .lib file but still have the  same problem. Do you have any idea why ?

Comment: try to install opengl also

Comment: Thanks for your advices and I fixed the problem. Just I linked the library from the settings instead of from the build options.